# Выбор элемента из DataGridView

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

Доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь выбрать значение XML-файла соответствующие значению в DataGridView.
Получилось занести значение в DataGrid и выбрать значение, НО выбор осуществляется не зависимо от строки, т.е значение будет одно не зависимо от того на какую строку кликнуть.

Class:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(ElementName = ("Document"))]
public class Document
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Personal")]
    public Personal Personal { get; set; }
}
public class Personal
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Work")]
    public Work work { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "info")]
    public string info { get; set; }
}
public class Work
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "users")]
    public List<Users> users { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "info")]
    public string info { get; set; }
}
public class Users
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "info")]
    public string info { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "user")]
    public List<User> user { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "company")]
    public string company { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "age")]
    public string age { get; set; }
}
```

Код:

```
public static XmlSerializer format = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Document));
    public static FileStream read = new FileStream(@"F:\XML2.xml", FileMode.Open);
    Document XmlDes = (Document)format.Deserialize(read);
    //По нажатию кнопки, заполняем DataGrid
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        foreach (var poisk in XmlDes.Personal.work.users)
        {
            userBindingSource.DataSource = poisk.user;
        }

    }
    //При нажатии на любую строку в DataGrid получаем значение
    private void userData_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var poisk in XmlDes.Personal.work.users)
        {
            //Вот тут загвоздка, я понимаю как вывести конкретный элемент, но как сделать, так что бы он соответствовал значению строки?
            CollectionUser.Rows.Add(poisk.user[0].age, poisk.user[0].name);
        }

    }
```

XML-файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Document>
<Personal>
    <Work info="Работающий">
        <users  info="Информация о работниках">
            <user name="Bill Gates">
                <company>Microsoft</company>
                <age>48</age>
            </user>
            <user name="Larry Page">
                <company>Google</company>
                <age>42</age>
            </user>
        </users>
    </Work>     
</Personal> 
</Document>
```

Пример: В DataGrid при нажатии на кнопку появляется атрибут(name) и два элемента(company & age), хотелось бы сделать так, при нажатии на первую строку, выводились значения первого элемента(Билла), в другом DataGrid и тоже самое при нажатии на вторую строку выводились значения второго элемента(Ларри).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо! Разобрался.

```
poisk.user[e.RowIndex].age, poisk.user[e.RowIndex].name
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы свести ручную работу к минимуму, можно поступить следующим образом, при условии, что у вас сделана привязка данных через `BindingSource`.

Подпишите первый `DataGridView` на событие `CellClick` (это удобнее, чем `CellContentClick`, так как не нужно точно попадать в содержимое ячейки).

```
private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var user = (User)userBindingSource.Current;
    dataGridView2.DataSource = new User[] { user };
}
```

Свойство `Current` указывает на текущий выделенный объект.

Чтобы второй датагрид отобразил данные, нужно привязать к нему *коллекцию*. Для этого динамически создаём массив, состоящий из одного элемента.

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется, что загвоздка тут:

```
 foreach (var poisk in XmlDes.Personal.work.users)
    {
        userBindingSource.DataSource = poisk.user;
    }
```

Зачем вы каждого юзера перебираетеся и присваиваете DataSource?

В данном случае получится, что в DataSource всегда находится 1 последний юзер.

Правильнее так, `userBindingSource.DataSource= XmlDes.Personal.work.users`

Comment: У меня на форме два DataGrid-a, с помощью данного цикла я заполняю первый DataGrid, всеми элементами и при нажатии на строку, во втором DataGrid-e должны отобразиться значения входящие в конкретный элемент <user>.

Comment: @Tibomso, зачем? Если сделать userBindingSource.DataSource= XmlDes.Personal.work.users , то все сделается само.

Comment: Я попробовал, не вышло) Появилась одна пустая строка

Comment: userBindingSource.DataSource = XmlDes.Personal.work.users[0].user; , вот так получается вывести на форму, но все равно проблема не в этом, но спасибо за совет)